# List only file names in directories and subdirectories in bash

Tags: bash

I need to create a list of files in a directory and all of its subdirectories. I've used

```
find . -type f
```

to get the list of files, but I only need the file name, not the path that leads to it.

So instead of returning this:

```
./temp2/temp3/file3.txt
./temp2/file2.txt
./file.txt
```

I need to return

```
file3.txt
file2.txt
file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. All of them worked, so I randomly selected the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

or better yet:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: why the tailing `\;` is needed?

Comment: Because everything after -exec is taken as argument to it, unless you end it with ;
However, there is also -exec command + , so that also changes the behavior of -exec. Check: man find

Answer (score 3):

You can use `printf` option in gnu `find`:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

For non-gnu `find` use `-execdir` and `printf`:

```
find . -type f -execdir printf "%s\n" {} +
```

Comment: `-execdir` is also a GNU extension.

Comment: Actually I have it on my BSD (OSX) `find` but `printf` isn't there

Comment: `s/GNU//` :) It's not POSIX, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f | xargs basename
```

The command `basename` strips the directories and outputs only the file name. Use `xargs` to chain the output of `find` as the input of `basename`.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer :)

The `-printf "%f"` is the best solution, but the `printf` is available only in the GNU find. For example on the OS X (and probably FreeBSD too) will print:

```
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator
```

for such cases, myself prefer the following

```
find . -type f | sed 's:.*/::'
```

It is faster (on the large trees) as the multiple `basename` execution.

Drawback, it will handle only filenames without the `\n` (newline) in the filenames. For handling such cases the easiest (and most universal - but slow) way is using the `basename`.

You can also use perl, like:

```
perl -MFile::Find -E 'find(sub{say if -f},".")'
```