# Linux - Print only filenames for the directory and sub-directories

Tags: linux, ls

I'm very new at Linux world.

I've the following directories on my linux (centos rhel fedora"):

```
Folder_Root:
    /root/main
        /root/main/files
            /root/main/files/file_1.txt
            /root/main/files/file_2.ssh
        /root/main/files/file_2.txt
    /root/main/file_3.txt
```

I'm trying to make a print of all the files in all the directories. Basically I am trying to get the following list:

```
file_1.txt
file_2.ssh
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
```

I already try 'ls' command and 'ls -al': `but it prints also the direcotry name.`

I also try to use 'ls -lR | more': `but it prints a lot of details that I don't want to use.`

Do you recommend any command?

Comment: How about `ls -1 -R`

Comment: Thanks :) Is great! But is it possible to exclude the details about the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using:

`find . -type f -exec basename {} \;`

or even:

`find . -type f -printf "%f\n"`

There is a similar question asked here and it has many answers, hope this helps:

[List only file names in directories and subdirectories in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995670/list-only-file-names-in-directories-and-subdirectories-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `find`:

```
find /root/main -type f
```